# Update a div in Django with some html text it's take html like a simple text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

I have a div on a page in django:
`<div id='log'> 
 </div>`
And with an ajax call i change text from this div in some random text with html codes included like:
`aala bala<br> fdsgfsdg <br>`
and the text should look like:

```
aala bala
fdsgfsdg

.
```

but the text looks like in first example : `aala bala<br> fdsgfsdg <br>`
I tried to include in text `{% autoescape off %}` but no succes till now.

```
    function view(id){
        $.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: "/test/view_log",
            data: { id: id},
            success:function(result){
                console.log(id);
                document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = result;
    }});
 }
```

The function it's working, will put the text in `log` div but html tag won't work and will be printed like text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
Import `mark_safe` from `django.utils.safestring` and return the code like that `mark_safe(code)`.

So code will look like:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
ret = 'blalblalala <br>dsdfs<br>'
return mark_safe(ret)
```